# Take intersection of data-frames in a for loop

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I have a data-frame of 4 columns

`DateTime | WindSpeed1 | WindSpeed2 |Direction`

I have created a for loop where I am taking `DateTime, WindSpeed1, WindSpeed2` columns iteratively and drop the rows with less than `3m/s` wind speed. My question is-

How to access the iterations of a for loop in order to merge those iterations for the common DateTime index.

I am using Python 2.7 by the way.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Ok, I have a small question for you, if you delete some rows(whihc are less than ~3m/s) both the dataframe will have different rows how can you merge them back ?

Comment: Would be easier to help if you could upload an example df, your code and explain why you are not filtering for where your windspeed < 3m/s but want to use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for not being clear enough. What I have mentioned above is actually for a GUI that I am programming.

As you can see below I am taking the data frame and delete wind speeds less than a user given value(result[4]). But since "v_range2" differs from iteration to iteration I would like to find a way to merge every iteration for the common DataTime.

Do you have an idea how I can do that?

```
for i in range(0, len(dirbins)):  # iterates on sectors
    meansd = []  # mean ws by sector
    heightsd = []
    for j in result[0]:  # iterates on ws
        if j != "":
            v = m.datafr(df).df[j]
            v_range1 = v >= result[4]
            v_range2 = v[v_range1]
            vidx = m.chnames().index(j)
            heightsd.append(float(str(m.channels[vidx].height)))
            meansd.append(v_range2[digitized_d == i].mean())  # mean ws by sector
```